# SnowFlake AWS Glue Integration Issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing issue with running Glue Jobs and getting errors. I am following [this](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-use-aws-glue-with-snowflake/) link as reference .

Jars Used :

- s3://Bucket/GlueJars/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.1.jar,
- s3://bucket/GlueJars/spark-snowflake_2.12-2.5.9-spark_2.4.jar

Snowflake version : select current_version()

- 4.5.2

what is the root cause of the issue ?

Error Logs From Glue :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.load.

: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V

at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Parameters$MergedParameters.<init>(Parameters.scala:263)

at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Parameters$.mergeParameters(Parameters.scala:257)

at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:59)

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)

at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)

at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)

at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)

at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)

at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)

at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)

at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)

at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)



2020-02-22 12:55:29,258 ERROR [Driver] ya

rn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logError(70)) - User application exited with status 1

2020-02-22 12:55:29,258 INFO [Driver] yarn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 1, (reason: User application exited with status 1)

2020-02-22 12:55:29,261 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

2020-02-22 12:55:29,264 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] server.AbstractConnector (AbstractConnector.java:doStop(318)) - Stopped Spark@dc562d7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0}

2020-02-22 12:55:29,266 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] ui.SparkUI (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Stopped Spark web UI at http://ip-172-32-153-220.ec2.internal:41151

2020-02-22 12:55:29,268 INFO [dispatcher-event-loop-1] yarn.YarnAllocator (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).

2020-02-22 12:55:29,269 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Shutting down all executors

2020-02-22 12:55:29,269 INFO [dispatcher-event-loop-2] cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Asking each executor to shut down

2020-02-22 12:55:29,272 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices

(serviceOption=None,

services=List(),

started=false)

2020-02-22 12:55:29,275 INFO [dispatcher-event-loop-2] spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!

2020-02-22 12:55:29,284 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] memory.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - MemoryStore cleared

2020-02-22 12:55:29,284 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] storage.BlockManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - BlockManager stopped

2020-02-22 12:55:29,285 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] storage.BlockManagerMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - BlockManagerMaster stopped

2020-02-22 12:55:29,287 INFO [dispatcher-event-loop-3] scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!

2020-02-22 12:55:29,290 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Successfully stopped SparkContext

2020-02-22 12:55:29,291 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] yarn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User application exited with status 1)

2020-02-22 12:55:29,300 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] impl.AMRMClientImpl (AMRMClientImpl.java:unregisterApplicationMaster(476)) - Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.

2020-02-22 12:55:29,401 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] yarn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Deleting staging directory hdfs://ip-172-32-141-92.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1582375951668_0001

2020-02-22 12:55:29,411 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] util.ShutdownHookManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Shutdown hook called

2020-02-22 12:55:29,412 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] util.ShutdownHookManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Deleting directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1582375951668_0001/spark-9c440196-6577-41ee-bf58-dfc1dcb6726a

2020-02-22 12:55:29,414 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] util.ShutdownHookManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Deleting directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1582375951668_0001/spark-9c440196-6577-41ee-bf58-dfc1dcb6726a/pyspark-c95bbd70-903e-488a-8bda-15c23b4bfe4f

End of LogType:stdout
```

Comment: It seems it fails when it tries to read from Snowflake. There could be several reasons for it. I suggest you to enable continuous logging, re-run the job and get more detailed error message: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html

Comment: Thanks .Enabled  the Continuous : LOGING Below is the driver Logs from AWS Glue ..Seems like issue with http client..Feb 23, 2020, 9:39:21 AM 20/02/23 04:09:21 WARN ApacheUtils: NoSuchMethodException was thrown when disabling normalizeUri. This indicates you are using an old version (< 4.5.8) of Apache http client. It is recommended to use http client version >= 4.5.9 to avoid the breaking change introduced in apache client 4.5.7 and the latency in exception handling. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1919 for more information

Comment: It is just a warning. Isn't there any error messages? Maybe you can share all logs after masking sensible info (such as user name, password, URL).

Comment: I'm getting the same error about 'disabling normalizeUri' stuff, could you solve it?